# wxpython editable ultimate listctr for one or two columns

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to make an ultimate listctr (Not listctr But an ultimate listctr which import from agw `from wx.lib.agw import ultimatelistctrl as ULC`).
using wx python which editable for only one or two columns. how to do that with example please?

this is my code:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl as ULC

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__init__
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((400, 321))
        self.SetTitle("frame")

        self.panel_1 = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        

        self.list_ctrl_1 = ULC.UltimateListCtrl(self.panel_1, wx.ID_ANY,agwStyle=ULC.ULC_REPORT | ULC.ULC_VRULES  )
        self.list_ctrl_1.InsertColumn(0, "A", format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_LEFT, width=-1)
        self.list_ctrl_1.InsertColumn(1, "B", format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_LEFT, width=-1)
        self.list_ctrl_1.InsertColumn(2, "C", format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_LEFT, width=-1)
        sizer_1.Add(self.list_ctrl_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        
        
        index = self.list_ctrl_1.InsertStringItem(0, "1")  
        self.list_ctrl_1.SetStringItem(index, 1,"2")
        self.list_ctrl_1.SetStringItem(index, 2,"3")

        index = self.list_ctrl_1.InsertStringItem(1, "1")  
        self.list_ctrl_1.SetStringItem(index, 1,"2")
        self.list_ctrl_1.SetStringItem(index, 2,"3")
        
        
        
        
        self.panel_1.SetSizer(sizer_1)

        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade
        


# end of class MyFrame

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

# end of class MyApp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

I want to make only first and second columns editable (column "A" and column"B" )

Comment: You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing what you have tried. No one is going to write your code for you even if you say "pretty please"

Comment: I have edited my question thank you for your comment . Not : I don't even know how to make ULC editable !

Comment: @yamka, maybe you need another control, like wx.grid?

Comment: you are right, It is easyer to use wx.grid but I have my own reason to use ULC